# How to use CMAltitudeHandler in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

```
[self.altimeter startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] withHandler:^(CMAltitudeData *altitudeData, NSError *error) {

}
```

This is how I will do this in Objective-C. I've read the Apple documentation but I have no idea what the documentation meant. I want to do the same thing in swift. I know this is a basic question but please help I can't find any other help online.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to make sure you have an altimeter in the device first, then start updates:

```
if CMAltimeter.isRelativeAltitudeAvailable() {
    altimeter.startRelativeAltitudeUpdatesToQueue(NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        [weak self] (altitudeData: CMAltitudeData!, error: NSError!) in

        println(altitudeData)
    }
}
```