# Access pressure value from barometer in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, sensors

I would like to access the pressure value of the barometer on an iPhone using Swift.  Can someone show me how to do that?  I am using `CLLocation` to access the altitude. Can the same class be used for pressure?

edit:

I put the following in my `viewDidLoad()` method but it's not printing anything... Please advise.

```
let altimeter = CMAltimeter()
    if CMAltimeter.isRelativeAltitudeAvailable() {
        altimeter.startRelativeAltitudeUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: { data, error in
            if !(error != nil) {
                print("Relative Altitude: \(data?.relativeAltitude)")
                print("Relative Pressure: \(data?.pressure)")
                self.pressLabel.text = String(describing: data?.pressure)
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: 1) Are you running this on a real device that actually has a barometer? 2) Does your code actually reach the call to `altimeter.startRelativeAltitudeUpdates`? 3) If so, is `error != nil`? If not, print `error`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barometer readings have nothing at all to do with location.

You need to look into the Core Motion library, specifically `CMAltitude` and `CMAltitudeData`. See [How to use CMAltitudeHandler in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540191/how-to-use-cmaltitudehandler-in-swift?s=5|0.6305) for an example.

Comment: Please see my updated code.  I'm having issues printing out the values.

Comment: Did you see my comment below your question?

Comment: yup I couldn't get any the error to print out but got it working by copying another example from github.

Comment: It would be helpful if you answered the questions I asked in that comment so a full answer can be provided. It will help future readers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a reference to `altimeter` otherwise it goes out of scope when `viewDidLoad()` finishes.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pressureLabel: UILabel!

    private var altimeter: CMAltimeter!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        altimeter = CMAltimeter()

        guard let data = data else {
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "unknoen error")
            return
        }

        print("Relative Altitude: \(data.relativeAltitude)")
        print("Relative Pressure: \(data.pressure)")
        self.pressureLabel.text = String(describing: data.pressure)
    }
}
```